# Alter column set not null fails

Tags: postgresql, alter, notnull, enterprisedb

Consider the following table with approximately 10M rows

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)
```

Then i applied the following alter

```
ALTER TABLE USER ADD COLUMN BUSINESS_ID    VARCHAR2(50);
--OK
UPDATE USER SET BUSINESS_ID = ID; //~1500 sec
--OK
ALTER TABLE USER ALTER COLUMN BUSINESS_ID SET NOT NULL;

    ERROR: column "business_id" contains null values
    SQL state: 23502
```

This is very strange since id column (which has been copied to business_id column) can't contain null values since it is the primary key, but to be sure i check it

```
select count(*) from USER where BUSINESS_ID is null
    --0 records
```

I suspect that this is a bug, just wondering if i am missing something trivial

Comment: I'm drawing a blank on why that would happen. Perhaps try the UPDATE with an explicit cast: `UPDATE "user" set business_id = ID::VARCHAR`

Comment: There is a chance it is related to the fact that "user" is a reserved word, but I don't really know. Reserved words list: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: There is no type `VARCHAR2` in Postgres. Something's off in your queston ..

Comment: @bma user is not the actual name of the table i just simplified it to write the question

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter database is EnterpriseDB with oracle compatibility enabled

Comment: @dimcookies: Worth mentioning. Don't have experience with EnterpriseDB, sorry.

Answer (score 23):

The only logical explanation would be a **concurrent `INSERT`**.
(Using `tbl` instead of the reserved word `user` as table name.)

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN BUSINESS_ID    VARCHAR2(50);
--OK
UPDATE tbl SET BUSINESS_ID = ID; //~1500 sec
--OK

-- concurrent INSERT HERE !!!

ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN BUSINESS_ID SET NOT NULL;</code></pre>
```

To prevent this, use instead:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl
  ADD COLUMN BUSINESS_ID VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';  -- or whatever is appropriate
...
```

You may end up with a default value in some rows. You might want to check.

Or run everything as transaction block:

```
BEGIN;
-- LOCK tbl; -- not needed
ALTER ...
UPDATE ...
ALTER ...
COMMIT;
```

You might take an exclusive lock to be sure, but [`ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock anyway. (Which is only released at the end of the transaction, like all locks.)

Comment: This is not the case unfortunately, there are no other connections to the database and not further insert statements were applied. Moreover the count function return 0 for `BUSINESS_ID is null`

Comment: Unfortunately i can not use a default value since this should be a unique column (a unique constraint is added after that statement). I tried the transaction block but that does not seem to change something. It seems to be a bug, we will contact the EnterpriseDb support, i just wanted to see if there was something obvious i was missing. In any case, thank you for your time

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/ddl-alter.html
Reference for the `alter table`

Comment: @Gokul: Yes, but 7.3 is ancient. Look at the manual pages for your Postgres version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-alter.html

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it wants a default value? [Postgresql docs on ALTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-alter.html):

> To add a column, use a command like this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN description text;
> ```
>
> The new column is initially filled with whatever default value is given (**null if you don't specify a DEFAULT clause**).

So,

```
ALTER TABLE USER ALTER COLUMN BUSINESS_ID SET DEFAULT="", 
                 ALTER COLUMN BUSINESS_ID SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I had to change this to `SET DEFAULT 0` in the case of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that at the same transaction. Add your column and update it. Then in a separate transaction set the not null constraint.

Comment: This was not run on the same transaction, they were separate commands